# PHP: Unexpected T_LIST

Tags: getimagesize, php, phplist

I am using the following code to deliver and embed a flash file, i am using getimagesize to get the width and height of the swf but it doesn't seem to like the list part... anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/header.php"); ?>
<h1><?php print($_GET['tag']); ?> <a href="#rl">(Related files)</a></h1>
<hr />
<div align="center">
<?php 
$project = $_GET['project'];
$file = $_GET['file'];
$tag = $_GET['tag']
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("files/".$project."/".$file.".swf");  
print('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" id="FlashID" title="'.$tag.'">');
print('<param name="movie" value="files/'.$project.'/'.$file.'.swf" />');
print('<param name="quality" value="high" />');
print('<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />');
print('<param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />');
print('<param name="expressinstall" value="/Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />');
?>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<?php print('<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="files/'.$project.'/'.$file.'.swf" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">') ?>
<!--<![endif]-->
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
      <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
      <param name="expressinstall" value="/Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
      <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
      <div>
        <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
      </div>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/footer.php"); ?>
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
  </object>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");
//-->
```

Comment: First of all I find it somewhat troubling that you're inserting GET parameters directly into a file path. That's is risky business.

Comment: they have already been prepared for the url on another page.

Comment: And yet you have no control over which parameters are used to call this page. Never trust any input that can, in any way, be modified by the user.

Comment: A valid point, but this project is only accessible to a select few who I can trust and need to be able to bookmark the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$tag = $_GET['tag']` needs an ;.

It's actually pretty easy to find, as you only have one `list`. Check the line above: boom you nailed It!

Comment: I can relate, happens to the best :D